# Vector Spaces, is it or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I don't understand when a set is determined to be a vector space or not, for example of given question is:
The set $\Bbb{R}^2$ with the usual scalar multiplication, but with addition defined by $[x,y] + [a,b] = [x+a+1, y+b]$ and with scalar multiplication defined by $r[x,y] = [xr+r-1, ry]$

I don't understand how to tell if this follows the properties of vector spaces.

Comment: You can start checking properties one at a time. For instance, is there a zero vector, i.e., is there some $(a,b)$ such that $(x,y)+(a,b)=(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)$? This vector need not be $(0,0)$. If you've found a zero vector, then can you find an additive inverse for each $(x,y)$?

Answer (score 3):

A vector space typically has $10$ properties to check:

1. Closure under addition. (If you add two vectors, you get another vector)
2. Additive commutativity. (The order in which you add two vectors doesn't matter)
3. Additive associativity. (Parentheses can be moved around freely)
4. Zero vector. (There is vector that you add to any other vector and nothing changes)
5. Additive inverses. (You have the negative of a vector.)
6. Closure under scalar multiplication (If you multiply a vector by a scalar, you get another vector)
7. Distributive law for multiplication ($c(u+v)=cu+cv$)
8. Distributive law for multiplication ($(c+d)u=cu+cd$)
9. Associative law for multiplication ($(cd)u=c(du)$)
10. Identity for multiplication ($1u=u$).

To determine if this is a vector space, you need to check all of these properties.  Let's get started:

1. $[x,y]+[a,b]=[x+a+1,y+b]$, when you add two vectors, you get a new vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so this is OK.  There would only be a possible problem if one were to restrict the part of $\mathbb{R}^2$ under consideration (which doesn't happen here.)
2. $[x,y]+[a,b]=[x+a+1,y+b]$ and $[a,b]+[x,y]=[a+x+1,b+y]=[x+a+1,y+b]=[x,y]+[a,b]$ so additive commutativity holds.
3. We compute $([x,y]+[a,b])+[w,z]=[x+a+1,y+b]+[w,z]=[x+a+1+w+1,y+b+z]=[x+a+w+2,y+b+z]$ and $[x,y]+([a,b]+[w,z])=[x,y]+[a+w+1,b+z]=[x+a+w+1+1,y+b+z]=[x+a+w+2,y+b+z]=([x,y]+[a,b])+[w,z]$ so associativity holds.
4. We want a vector $[a,b]$ so that $[x,y]+[a,b]=[x,y]$.  Since $[x,y]+[a,b]=[x+a+1,y+b]$, we need $x+a+1=x$ (so $a=-1$ and $y+b=y$, so $b=0$).  Observe that $[x,y]+[-1,0]=[x-1+1,y+0]=[x,y]$ so $[-1,0]$ is the zero.
5. We want a vector $[a,b]$ so that $[x,y]+[a,b]=[-1,0]$.  Since $[x,y]+[a,b]=[x+a+1,y+b]$, to get this to equal $[-1,0]$, we need $x+a+1=-1$ so $a=-2-x$ and for $y+b=0$, $b=-y$.  Therefore, the negative of $[x,y]$ is $[-2-x,-y]$.
6. Since $r[x,y]=[xr+r-1,ry]$, which si a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ this is OK.  There could only be a problem if we restricted our attention to a part of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
7. Consider $r([x,y]+[a,b])=r[x+a+1,y+b]=[r(x+a+1)+r-1,r(y+b)]=[rx+ra+2r-1,ry+rb]$.  On the other hand, $r[x,y]+r[a,b]=[rx+r-1,ry]+[ra+r-1,rb]=[rx+r-1+ra+r-1+1,ry+rb]=[rx+ra+2r-1,ry+rb]=r([x,y]+[a,b])$.
8. Consider $(c+d)[x,y]=[(c+d)x+(c+d)-1,(c+d)y]=[cx+dx+c+d-1,cy+dy]$ and $c[x,y]+d[x,y]=[cx+c-1,cy]+[dx+d-1,dy]=[cx+c-1+dx+d-1+1,cy+dy]=[cx+dx+c+d-1,cy+dy]=(c+d)[x,y]$.
9. Consider $(cd)[x,y]=[cdx+cd-1,cdy]$ and $c(d[x,y])=c[dx+d-1,dy]=[c(dx+d-1)+c-1,cdy]=[cdx+cd-1,cdy]=(cd)[x,y]$.
10. Consider $1[x,y]=[1x+1-1,1y]=[x,y]$ so the multiplicative identity holds.

Therefore, all $10$ properties hold and this is a vector space (unless I made a mistake somewhere - very possible).  If anyone wants to make this prettier, please feel free to change this up, I got tired somewhere around property 7.

Comment: I'm just switching the roles of $[x,y]$ and $[a,b]$ in the original formulation.  $$[x,y]+[a,b]=[x+a+1,y+b]$$ $$[a,b]+[x,y]=[a+x+1,b+y]$$  It's the same form, just change the position letters.

Comment: @BobDoe By the definition of addition that we're given. Don't worry too much about whether we use $a$ or $x$. The important thing is what part goes where.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mainly used ways to check if a set is a Vector Space.

- The first, and most tiresome way, is to check if the **$8$ Axioms of Vector Spaces** are properties of the given set.
- The second one, which is easier, is to simply  check if the given set is a **subspace** of a set that we already know is a Vector Space.

---

Since this set has its own definition of a addition and scalar multiplication I would suggest we check using the 8 Axioms. You can do this using the definition included in this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition

I hope I helped.

Answer (score 1):

An easier (but slicker) approach than my other approach to this problem is to consider the map 
$$
\phi([x,y])=[x+1,y]
$$
into the usual copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Now, this map commuted with addition and scalar multiplication.  In fact,
\begin{align*}
\phi([x,y]+[a,b])&=\phi([x+a+1,y+b])=[x+a+2,y+b]\\
\phi([x,y])+\phi([a,b])&=[x+1,y]+[a+1,b]=[x+a+2,y+b]
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\phi(r[x,y])&=\phi([rx+r-1,ry])=[rx+r,ry]\\
r\phi([x,y])&=r[x+1,y]=[rx+r,ry]
\end{align*}
Therefore, this is really copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$, just in a disguised manner (a pullback of the standard operations).

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to check whether $\Bbb R_\oplus,\otimes$ (swhere $\oplus$ is your redefined addition, and $\otimes$ is your redefined scalar multiplication), satisfies the definition of a vector space, which consists of eight axioms (plus closure under addition and multiplication, which are both obvious).

Commutativity of addition is OK: 
$$
\mathbf{a} \oplus \mathbf{b}=(a_1+b_1+1, a_2+b_2)=(b_1+a_1+1, b_2+a_2)=\mathbf{b} \oplus \mathbf{a}
$$

Associativity of addition is OK; this proof uses commutativity:
$$
(\mathbf{a} \oplus \mathbf{b}) \oplus \mathbf{c} = (a_1+b_1+1, a_2+b_2) \oplus (c_1,c_2) =
(a_1+b_1+c_1+2, (b_2+c_2)+a_2) = ((b_1+c_1+1)+a_1+1, (b_2+c_2)+a_2)=(\mathbf{b} \oplus \mathbf{c}) \oplus \mathbf{a}=\mathbf{a} \oplus (\mathbf{b} \oplus \mathbf{c})
$$
If $(i_1,i_2)$ is the identity element of $\oplus$, then for all $\mathbf{a}=(a_1,a_2)$, 
$$ (i_1+a_1+1,i_2+a_2)=(a_1,a_2) \implies \mathbf{I_\oplus} = (-1,0) 
$$
and this works for all  $\mathbf{a}$ so additive identity is OK.

Additive inverse:  Given 
$\mathbf{a}=(a_1,a_2)$,
$$
= (a_1,a_2)\oplus (-a_1-2 , -a_2) = (-1,0)=\mathbf{I_\oplus} =  (-a_1-2 , -a_2)\oplus (a_1,a_2)
$$
so additive inverse is satisfied, with $\ominus(a_1,a_2)=(-a_1-2 , -a_2)$.

Multiplicative consistency requires $r\otimes(s\otimes \mathbf{a}) = (rs)\otimes \mathbf{a}$ and that is OK:
$$
r\otimes(s\otimes \mathbf{a})=r\otimes(sa_1+s-1,sa_2)=(rsa_1+rs-r+r-1,rsa_2)\\
=(rsa_1+rs-1, rsa_2)
= (rs)\otimes \mathbf{a} 
$$
The identity element for $\otimes$ has to be the real number $1$ atnd that works:
$$
1\otimes(a_1,a_2) = (1\cdot a_1 - 1 + 1,a_2) = (a_1,a_2)
$$
Distributivity of scalar multiplication over vector addition is OK:
$$
r\otimes (\mathbf a \oplus \mathbf b) =  
r\otimes (a_1+b_1+1,a_2+b_2) 
\\ = (r(a_1+b_1+1)+r-1,r(a_2+b_2)) \\
(r\otimes \mathbf a) \oplus (r\otimes \mathbf b) 
= (ra_1+r-1,ra_2) \oplus (rb_1+r-1,rb_2)\\
= (ra_1+r-1+rb_1+r-1+1,ra_2+rb_2
\\= (r(a_1+b_1+1)+r-1,r(a_2+b_2)) = r\otimes (\mathbf a \oplus \mathbf b)
$$
Finally, distributivity of scalar-vector multiplication over scalar addition is OK:
$$
(r+s)\mathbf{a} = ( (r+s)a_1 + (r+s) -1, (r+s)a_2 )
\\ r\mathbf{a} \oplus s\mathbf{a} = 
(ra_1+r-1,ra_2) \oplus (sa_1+s-1,sa_2)
\\ = ((ra_1+r-1)+(sa_1+s-1)+1,ra_2+sa_2) =
 ( (r+s)a_1 + (r+s) -1, (r+s)a_2 )=(r+s)\mathbf{a} 
$$

Since this combination o operators meets all the defining axioms, the set under these operators forms a vector space.